# In Perl, how can I tell split not to strip empty trailing fields?

Tags: perl

Was trying to count the number of lines in a string of text (including empty lines). A little surprised by the behavior of `split`.  Had expected the following to output `2` but it printed `1` on my `perl 5.14.2`.

```
$str = "hello\
world\n\n";
@a = split(/\n/, $str);
print $#a, "\n";
```

Seems that `split()` is insensitive to consecutive `\n` (add more `\n's` at the end of the string will not increase the printout).   The only I can get it sort of close to giving the number of lines is

```
$str = "hello\
world\n\n";
@a = split(/(\n)/, $str);
printf "%d\n", ($#a + 1)/2, "\n";
```

But it looks more like a workaround than a straight solution. Any ideas?

Comment: to just count newlines, do `$newlines = $str =~ y/\n//;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`perldoc -f split`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#split):

> If LIMIT is negative, it is treated as if it were instead
>               arbitrarily large; as many fields as possible are produced.
>
> If LIMIT is omitted (or, equivalently, zero), then it is usually
>               treated as if it were instead negative but with the exception that
>               **trailing empty fields are stripped** (empty leading fields are
>               always preserved); if all fields are empty, then all fields are
>               considered to be trailing (and are thus stripped in this case).

```
$ perl -E 'my $x = "1\n2\n\n"; my @x = split /\n/, $x, -1; say $#x'
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that you are using $#a when scalar @a is what you are actually looking for?

I apologize if you are already aware of this or if this is not the issue, but $#a returns the index of the last element of @a and (scalar @a) returns the number of elements that @a contains.  Since array indexing starts at 0, $#a is one less than scalar @a.